# How do I call an empty or default version of a model in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model

For something I'm writing, I want to get an empty copy of a model, or a copy with default values.

So, normally it might return something like

```
array(
  'id' => '4',
  'name' => 'Object name',
  'somekey' => 'Some key\'s value',
  'someotherkey' => '1',
  'created' => '2012-04-22 17:11:31',
  'modified' => '2012-04-22 17:11:31'
)
```

Instead I would like it to return an array with the keys intact, but the values empty completely, or even better (if possible) with a default values that I could specify in the model itself.  Is this possible?

Comment: When you use `Model::create()` it fills in any keys you have set with default values in your schema.

Comment: If you want to make it an answer, I'll definitely choose it, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Cool, will do. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to create a user with the default values filled, you can use `Model::create()`. It searches the schema for default values that you have defined for the database and fills in the record data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the Model method [schema()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelschema).
That returns all the table fields/types. For example:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function emptyDataset() {
        $fields = $this->schema();

        if(is_array($fields)) {
            return array_keys($fields);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's definitely a great start.  I suppose from there I could set the few fields I want to have defined default empty values.